# How to combine both of these IF statements into one?

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement

I want to run an alert if the viewport is wider than 1250px and if the user is near the bottom of the page.

I currently have the two snippets of code which work individually...

```
function checkSize(){
    if ($(window).width() > 1250) {
        alert('hello');
    }
}

checkSize();

$(window).resize(function() {
    checkSize();
});
```

and the other snippet which detects how far the user has scrolled down...

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
   if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() > $(document).height() - 700) {
       alert('hello');
   }
});
```

How can I combine the two in one if statement? I have tried this but it does not seem to work..

```
function checkSize(){
    if ($(window).width() > 1250 && $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() > $(document).height() - 700) {
        alert('hello');
    }
}


checkSize();

$(window).resize(function() {
    checkSize();
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following discussion in comments. This seems to be working:

```
function checkSize(){
  if($(window).width() > 1250 && $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() > $(document).height() - 700) {
    console.log('hello');
  }
}

checkSize();
$(window).scroll(checkSize);
$(window).resize(checkSize);
```

[Demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KBdvJ)

Comment: Which of the default precedence rules needs to be overridden with parentheses? See the link in my comment to In God I Trust.

Comment: thanks, although I think I tried that and it didn't seem to work, i have a demo here http://codepen.io/anon/pen/metwb

Comment: In this example `$(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() > $(document).height() - 700)` is never true. It stars being true around `-1500` instead of `-700`

Comment: "Do you know how better it can be written" - please explain what you need? Trigger should alert when window width is bigger than 1250 and ... ?

Comment: I just updated my last comment. I want the alert to popup when width is 1250px or wider AND if the user is near the bottom of the window

Comment: Yes agree, however now you lose the browser resize function. So if you are on a small viewport, make it wider, while still at bottom of the page, the alert does not appear. Can you fix this, then I will mark as correct answer?

Comment: Updated the demo. Tried this: shrink window, scroll down, widen window - got a bunch of "hello" in console.

Comment: I also updated event handlers attachment a bit, but feel free to change back.

Answer (score 2):

```
(($(window).width() > 1250) && ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height()) > $(document).height() - 700)
```

You need to place `()` to show what you what to calculate!

Comment: According to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence the default precedence should be equivalent to this. What am I missing?

Comment: @Barmar because when you process this, `$(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() > $(document).height()`, it is first dividing the window.height by the document height and adding on to the first scrollTop

Comment: `+` has higher precedence than `>`. And there's no division operator in there, so why would it be dividing anything?

Comment: unfortunately this didn't work, I have set up a demo here so you can see http://codepen.io/anon/pen/metwb

Comment: @Barmar actually, I dont know what I'm waffling about. Thought the `>` was a divide sign! I'm exhausted!

Comment: @Adam your demo is working, even without the parenthesis... when you scroll to bottom and resize the window, you get the alert...